# associative array check any column is empty or not

Tags: php, arrays

I have associative array like -

```
[0] => Array
       (
           [date] => 2018-06-22
           [id] => 2282991
           [type] => VIDEO
           [domain] => 
           [code] => Austin
           [address] => Phone
       )

   [1] => Array
       (
           [date] => 2018-06-22
           [id] => 2282991
           [type] => VIDEO
           [domain] => 
           [code] => 
           [address] => Phone
       )

   [3] => Array
       (
           [date] => 2018-06-22
           [id] => 2282991
           [type] => VIDEO
           [domain] => 
           [code] => Austin
           [address] => Phone
       )
```

I need to check is there any column having all the values are blank. 
That means it should return only domain from above array because it is blank everywhere.

Is there any way to do this with minimum use of forloop? I need to check this for all these columns.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: yes, quite possible using `for` loop, `foreach` loop is preferable

Comment: 1/ What do you try? 2/ What do you mean with `it should return only domain from above array because it is blank everywhere`, can you explain and who us the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work if your subarray having same number of keys.Like "Date, id, Type etc".

```
 $array = [ 
        [ "date" => "2018-06-22", "id" => 2282991, "type" => "VIDEO", "domain" =>'', "code" => "Austin", "address" => "Phone"],
        [ "date" => "2018-06-22", "id" => 2282991, "type" => "VIDEO", "domain" =>'', "code" => "", "address" => "Phone"],
        [ "date" => "2018-06-22", "id" => 2282991, "type" => "VIDEO", "domain" =>'', "code" => "Austin", "address" => "Phone"]
    ];

   $empty = [];     
    foreach($array[0] as $key=>$val){
        $error = array_column($array, $key);
        if(empty (array_filter($error)) ) {
            $empty[] =  $key;
        }
    }
print_r($empty);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => domain
)
```